# Usar @import em less passando variável como parâmetro

Tags: less

Estou fazendo um *mixin* em *less* e preciso usar *@import* passando uma variável como parâmetro.

Exemplo:

**change-theme.less**

```
.change-theme(@theme) {
    @import @theme;
    // Another code goes here
}
```

**theme.less**

```
@import "change-theme";
.theme-black {
    .change-theme("variables/my_black_theme");
}
.theme-green {
    .change-theme("variables/my_green_theme");
}
```

Ele não aceita variável no parâmetro, existe alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Error:

> { [Error: malformed import statement in file change-theme.less line no. 6]
>     type: 'Syntax',
>     filename: 'change-theme.less',
>     index: 124,
>     line: 6,
>     callLine: NaN,
>     callExtract: undefined,
>     column: 2,
>     extract: [ '', '  @import @theme;', '' ],
>     message: 'malformed import statement in file change-theme.less line no. 6',
>     stack: undefined,
>     lineNumber: 6,
>     fileName: 'change-theme.less',
>     name: 'Error',
>     showStack: false,
>     showProperties: true,
>     plugin: 'gulp-less',
>     __safety: { toString: [Function] } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables interpolation it works:

`@import "my_folder/@{theme}";`

Comment: Marca como resposta ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível. Primeiramente, acho que ficaria legal se você colocasse um valor default para esse parâmetro. Um exemplo dessa aplicação:

```
.margin(@top: 4px; @left: 4px; @bottom: 4px;  @right: 4px;) {
    margin: @arguments;
}

a {
  .margin(10px, 5px, 5px, 20px);
}
```

Dá pra fazer o envio de parâmetros, agora é saber a aplicação disso para o que você quer é valida.

Comment: Desta maneira consegui fazer funcionar, mas quando uso o *@import*, dá erro de sintaxe, vou atualizar a pergunta.